# Read JSON field in depending on type specified by other field

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have JSON like the following:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "timestamp" : "1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00",
    "attributes" : [
      {
        "name" : "Weather",
        "value" : "Cloudy",
        "fieldDataType" : "string"
      },
      {
        "name" : "pH",
        "value" : 7.2,
        "fieldDataType" : "double"
      },
      {
        "name" : "Quality Indicator",
        "value" : 2,
        "fieldDataType" : "integer"
      }
    ]
}
```

and I want to parse it using the Play JSON libs. I've been able to handle the "timestamp" but am having difficulty in parsing the "value" field as its type is determined by "fieldDataType". So far I have:

```
sealed trait AttributeValue
case class AttributeInt(value: Integer) extends AttributeValue
case class AttributeDouble(value: Double) extends AttributeValue
case class AttributeString(value: String) extends AttributeValue

case class Attribute (name: String, value: AttributeValue)

object Attribute {    
    implicit val attributeReads: Reads[Attribute] = (
        (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "fieldDataType").read[String] // ???
    )(Attribute.apply _)
}
```

I want to be able to read the "fieldDataType" and then, depending on its value, read in the "value" field. So if the "fieldDataType" is string then read the "value" as a string, if the "fieldDataType" is an "integer" then read the "value" as an integer etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I did allow myself to change your `AttributeInt` declaration to:

```
case class AttributeInt(value: Int) extends AttributeValue
```

to use default `Int` parser

next you could define such `Reads` provider:

```
val attributeByDatatype: PartialFunction[String, JsPath => Reads[AttributeValue]] = {
  case "integer" => _.read[Int].map(AttributeInt)
  case "double" => _.read[Double].map(AttributeDouble)
  case "string" => _.read[String].map(AttributeString)
}
```

being `PartialFunction` allow it not only to handle specific datatypes but also supply information about what datatype it knows and what it does not, this is useful with `Reads.collect` method, while resulting `Reads` could be target for `flatMap`

Now you could change your `attributeReads` as follows:

```
object Attribute {
  implicit val attributeReads: Reads[Attribute] = (
      (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "fieldDataType")
      .read[String]
      .collect(ValidationError("datatype unknown"))(attributeByDatatype)
      .flatMap(_(JsPath \ "value"))
  )(Attribute.apply _)
}
```